# Component doesn't reinit on query parameter change angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I'm using angular 2 and latest router component to implement a search feature. When I first time clicked the search button then router navigate to search component and retrieve data from the service. After that when I change the search text data does not changes but query parameter changes.

**navbar.component.ts**

```
    @Component({
    selector:'navbar',
    template:`
    <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" 
       name="srch-term" id="srch-term" [(ngModel)] = "search_text">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="search()">
         <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
       </button>
   </div>
     </div>`,
        styleUrls:['app/navbar/navbar.component.css'],
        directives:[LoginComponent,SignupComponent,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
        })
    export class NavbarComponent {
        State: NavbarState = "PUBLIC";

        profileNavElement: NavbarElement;
        userNameString: string;
        search_text : string = '';
    search(){
            console.log(this.search_text);
            if(this.search_text){
                this.router.navigate(["/search"],{
                    queryParams:{query:this.search_text}
                });
            }

        }
```

**serach.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute,Router,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES}  from '@angular/router';
import { SearchService } from './search.service';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'search',
    templateUrl: 'search.component.html',
    styleUrls:['./search.component.css'],
    providers:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,SearchService]
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

    query:string = '';
    videos:Object[] ;
    resultFound:boolean=false ;
    resultNotFound:boolean=false;

    constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,
                private router:Router,
                private _searchService:SearchService) {

                }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.router.routerState
            .queryParams
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.query = data['query'];
        });
        this.getSearchResult();
    }


    getSearchResult(){
        this._searchService.getSearchResult(this.query)
            .subscribe((result) => {
                this.resultFound = true;
                this.resultNotFound = false;
                this.videos = result;
            },
            (error) => {
                this.resultFound = false;
                this.resultNotFound = true;
            });
    }

}
```

What should I do now ? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

That is as designed. When only route parameters change the component is reused.

You can just move the `getSearchResult()` inside `subscribe()` so that it is called every time when the parameters change:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.routerState
        .queryParams
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.query = data['query'];
            this.getSearchResult();
    });
}
```

There are plans to support custom behavior but probably not before final.